# Problem with \craft\elements\User::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE

Tags: plugin-development, craft3

Having an issue with using the event \craft\elements\User::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE in a plug in. I am adding a new user to a group. My goal is to have the newly added user automatically added to the same user group as the logged in user. This is my code:

```
Event::on(
    \craft\elements\User::class,
    \craft\elements\User::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE,
    function(ModelEvent  $event) {
        if (Craft::$app->getUser()->getIsAdmin() == false){
            $loggedInUser = Craft::$app->getUser();
            $userGroupUser = new UserGroup_User();
            $userGroupUser->groupId = $loggedInUser->getIdentity()->getGroups()[0]['id'];
            $userGroupUser->userId = $event->sender->id;
            $result = $userGroupUser->insert();
         }
    }
);
```

I have put a breakpoint on the code after the if statement and then checked the users table - the new user is not in the users table yet.

I would expect that the new user would be in the table at this point. Is this transaction being saved and executed later? If so is there something I can do to force the transaction to save the new user?

Is this possible a bug?

I do not get any error messages. Why?

EDIT: I should also mention that the usergroup has permission to add users in their own usergroup.

Comment: You'll need to use the `afterSaveElement` event https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/services/Elements.php#L534

Comment: Thanks @robin. Not making sense to me though. Here is the doc on the event I was using: [EVENT_AFTER_SAVE](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-element.html#event-after-save.). What does not make sense is the docs says "The event that is triggered after the element is saved". When I changed this to use the event: \craft\services\elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT the event does not fire.

Comment: It does fire. The users `afterSave` is still inside the transaction so if you break it up (via breakpoint) the user isn't inside the table at that moment. The event `AfterSaveElement` is fired after the transaction is done, so after the element is stored

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your specific error is, but whenever I use

```
Event::on(
\craft\elements\User::class,
\craft\elements\User::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE,
```

I need to provide the next parameter with a `\yii\base\Event` callback, not a `\craft\events\ModelEvent` one.

Maybe that's your case as well ?
 You can also use `\yii\base\ModelEvent`, but not the craft one, as the craft ModelEvent does not extend `\yii\base\Event`

Comment: That did not resolve the issue. I will post an "answer" with more detail below as it will not fit in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on this for days now. 
Using either:

> \yii\base\Event

or

> ElementEvent

Seems to register the event and it fires after a new user is entered.
That's a good tip though.

My code currently looks like this:

```
Event::on(
    Elements::class,
    Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT,
    function(ElementEvent  $event) {
        if (Craft::$app->getUser()->getIsAdmin() == false){
            $loggedInUser = Craft::$app->getUser();
            $userGroupUser = new UserGroup_User();
            $loggedInUserGroup = $loggedInUser->getIdentity()->getGroups()[0]['id'];
            $newUserId =  $event->element['id'];
            $userGroupUser->groupId = $loggedInUserGroup;
            $userGroupUser->userId = $newUserId;
            $result = $userGroupUser->save();
         }
    }
);
```

Things I know:

1. The code fires when I add a new user. I know this by placing a
   breakpoint on any line in the callback function.
2. The callback code will NOT add a new row in the usergroups_users
   table for the brand new entered user. Let's say that user name is
   "Test1".
3. After I allow the entry process to finish Test1 now shows up in the users table as a user with ID #50. The brand new "Test1" does not show up in the usergroups_uers table even though the callback code executed.
4. Next if I change the callback code to use the user ID (50) of the newest user (Test1) that I just entered and then go and create a new user called test "Test2" the callback function will create a record for user "Test1" (user ID 50) will be entered into the usergroups_users table. I will see that record if I examine the usergroups_user table.

Code:

```
Event::on(
    Elements::class,
    Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT,
    function(ElementEvent  $event) {
        if (Craft::$app->getUser()->getIsAdmin() == false){
            $userGroupUser = new UserGroup_User();
            $userGroupUser->groupId = 1;
            $userGroupUser->userId = 50;
            $result = $userGroupUser->save();
         }
    }
);
```

It's like the insert for the usergroups_users is silently failing if the user was just entered. It could also be that something was not committed???

I am new to Craft so it could be a noobie error but this one has me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your issue is, the following Code works as expected. Of course you should check if the element is an instance of `craft\elements\User` and the user is not already in the group.

```
Event::on(
    craft\services\Elements::class,
    craft\services\Elements::EVENT_AFTER_SAVE_ELEMENT,
    function(craft\events\ElementEvent  $event) {
            $userGroupUser = new craft\records\UserGroup_User();
            $userGroupUser->groupId = 1;
            $userGroupUser->userId = $event->element->getId();
            if(!$userGroupUser->save()){
                Craft::error('Could not save group ' . Json::encode($userGroupUser->getErrors()));
            }
    }
);
```